# System.Serialization Exception ===> Vimeo Videos are not playing on IOS/Android on Xamarin.forms App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, vimeo, vimeo-api

[image]All of a sudden the videos hosted on Vimeo are not being loaded. 
It is failing after the serialization part. Not able to understand as this started happening all of a sudden.

```cs
try
{
    Match vimeoMatch = VimeoVideoRegex.Match(VideoId);

    if (vimeoMatch.Success)
        VideoId = vimeoMatch.Groups[1].Value;

    var videoInfoUrl = $"https://player.vimeo.com/video/{VideoId}/config";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var videoPageContent = client.GetStringAsync(videoInfoUrl).Result;
        var videoPageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(videoPageContent);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(videoPageBytes))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(VimeoVideo));
            var metaData = (VimeoVideo)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            var files = metaData.request.files.progressive;

            // Exact match
            var url = files.OrderByDescending(s => s.width).Select(s => s.url).FirstOrDefault();

            Debug.WriteLine($"Stream URL: {url}");
            return VideoSource.FromUri(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am quite confused as to what you are asking. You have simply provided a statement

Comment: @loCalisto There is an encoding issue and the video is not being downloaded on my app.

Comment: Which specific line is failing?  Is it throwing an exception or error?  Has the Vimeo json format changed?

Comment: @pree please follow these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It throws an exception. I have added the screenshot for further clarification. The line after metaData fails. @ Jason @loCalisto

Comment: that error seems fairly obvious - the json contains a null in a field that is expecting an int